# Uncompress tar.bz2 from s3 and move the files back to s3 from Pyhon

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Suppose I have a `bzip2` compressed `tar` archive file `x.tar.bz2` stored in `s3`. I would like to decompress it and place back to `s3`. This can be achieved by:

```
from s3fs import S3FileSystem
fs = S3FileSystem()

import tarfile

with fs.open('s3://path_to_source/x.tar.bz2', 'rb') as f:
    r = f.read()
with open('x.tar.bz2', mode='wb') as localfile:     
    localfile.write(r)
tar = tarfile.open('x.tar.bz2', "r:bz2")
tar.extractall(path='extraction/path')
tar.close()

fs.put('extraction/path', f's3://path_to_destination/x', recursive=True)
```

Within the solution above, I am saving the file content twice into my local disc. I have the following questions (solution is expected to be done using Python):

1. Is it possible (using `tarfile` module) to load data directly from s3 and also extract it there avoiding to store data on local drive?
2. Is it possible to make this job in a streaming mode without need to have the whole `x.tar.bz2` (or at least the uncompressed archive `x.tar`) file in memory?

Comment: I've not worked with boto but i would guess that https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object would return you a fileobj that you can then pass to Tarfile constructor ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tarfile.open` accepts a file-like object as the `fileobj` argument, so you can pass to it the file object you get from `S3FileSystem.open`. You can then iterate through the `TarInfo` objects in the tar object, and open the corresponding path in S3 for writing:

```
with fs.open('s3://path_to_source/x.tar.bz2', 'rb') as f:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:bz2') as tar:
        for entry in tar:
            with fs.open(f'path_to_destination/{entry.name}', mode='wb') as writer:
                writer.write(tar.extractfile(entry).read())
```